# Pandas GroupBy : How to get top n values based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, dataframe

forgive me if this is a basic question but i am new to pandas. I have a dataframe with with a column A and i would like to get the top n rows based on the count in Column A. For instance the raw data looks like

```
A  B  C
x 12  ere
x 34  bfhg
z 6   bgn
z 8   rty
y 567 hmmu,,u
x 545 fghfgj
x 44  zxcbv
```

Note that this is just a small sample of the data that i am actually working with.

So if we look at Column A, value x appears 4 times,y appears 2 times and z appears 1 time. How can i get the top n values for Column A based on this count?

```
print df.groupby(['A']).sum()
```

this gives me

```
A      B

x      6792117
```

but when i do

```
print len(df.groupby(['A']).get_group('x'))
```

i get

```
21
```

furthermore

```
len(df.index)
```

gives me

```
23657
```

so how can the count of `'A' == 'x'` be `6792117` as seen in the result of group by? what am i missing?

**Update**

consider

```
print df.groupby(['A']).describe()
```

gives me

```
     Tags           DocID

x    count      21.000000
     mean   323434.142857
     std     35677.410292
     min    266631.000000
     25%    292054.000000
     50%    325575.000000
     75%    347450.000000
     max    380286.000000
```

which makes sense. i just want to get the row which has the max count as per column A.

**Update2**

i did

```
print df.groupby(['A'],as_index=False).count()
```

i get

```
         A       B      C
0        x       21     21
1        y       11     11
2        z        8      8
```

so basically, for Column A, tag x has 21 entries in Column B and 21 in Column C. ColumnsB and C are unique in my case. which is good. now how do i get the top n rows with respect to column C?

**Update3**

So i tried

```
import heapq
print heapq.nlargest(3,df.groupby(['A'],as_index=False).count()['C'])
```

and i get

```
[151, 85, 72]
```

so i know that for Column A, i have the above counts as the top 3 counts. But i still dont know which value of Column A do these counts refer to? For example which value in Column A has a count of 151? Is there any way to link this information?

Comment: Please post raw input data, code to reproduce your df, at the moment this is all speculative without data and code to reproduce your observations

Comment: I think downvote is because you dont use your sample data.

Comment: Can you share data, which using, to dropbox or google docs? Because I try use your sample data, but my output is different as your.

Comment: unfortunately, the data is proprietary. by the way what did you try? can you post it as an answer?

Comment: No, problem. You can try use your sample and change your outputs by this input. And the best is post your recommended output (from your sample data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can use function [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html).

I try your sample data and get top 2 rows by column `C`:

```
print df
   A    B        C
0  x   12      ere
1  x   34     bfhg
2  z    6      bgn
3  z    8      rty
4  y  567  hmmu,,u
5  x  545   fghfgj
6  x   44    zxcbv

dcf = df.groupby(['A'],as_index=False).count()
print dcf
   A  B  C
0  x  4  4
1  y  1  1
2  z  2  2

#get 2 largest rows by column C
print dcf.nlargest(2,'C')
   A  B  C
0  x  4  4
2  z  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach that i tried

```
import heapq

dcf =  df.groupby(['A'],as_index=False).count()
print dcf.loc[dcf['C'].isin(heapq.nlargest(5,dcf['C']))].sort(['C'],ascending=False)
```

gives me

```
      A       B      C
1664  g       151    151
1887  k       85     85
1533  q       72     72
53    y       68     68
1793  t       62     62
```

verified by

```
print len(df.loc[df["A"]=="g"])
```

gives me

```
151
```

so i get the desired results as i can see the top 5 values based on the count from Column A. but surely there must be a better way of doing this?